# Dell printer not working after firmware update

Tags: printer, firmware

I have a Dell b2375dfw. I carried out a firmware update on it for the first time yesterday since I bought it in 2016. The printer does not accept print commands anymore. When I power it up, it just shows blank menus. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You mean other than contact Dell about their product?

Comment: Was it [this firmware](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=p9dpc)? See in the link the section "Installation instructions". And why update in 2021 with firmware from 2018?

Comment: yes that is the one; I just thought I have not updated the firmware yet so why not and now I am in this terrible problem;

Comment: Honestly.. was it working in the first place?  "If it ain't broke.. don't fix it".

Comment: yes it has worked without any problem in the last 4 years; I can see why I should not have tried this firmware update now; my life is ruined

Comment: Why do people even think that updating printer f/w is useful? Only ever do it if it fixes a bug **you are experiencing** or it installs a new feature you would like (and you believe in Santa Claus)

Comment: I would attempt to reflash the firmware just in case it got corrupted.  Otherwise try google to find the older firmware and re-flash with that one,

Comment: I can't find the old firmware. I tried to reflash the new one but no avail. I was able to reach the special system menu where we enter password 1934 and can initiate a system reset. However, it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Turn on the printer
- Run Device Manager
- Find your printer - it may perhaps be under "Print queues"
- Right-click in it and choose Properties
- If you have a Driver tab, look if a button exists called "Rollback driver":

  - If it exists, use it and reboot
  - Else continue on
- In Device Manager, right-click the printer and select "Uninstall device"
- If asked, choose to delete the driver
- Reboot. You are now using the Windows generic print driver, which may be good enough.
  Otherwise, you will need to find a download for your old driver.

Comment: the issue is not windows drivers, it is the firmware inside the printer that is corrupted

Comment: In that case, see if one of the utilities in the [link](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-b2375dnf/drivers) can force the firmware update. If not, then contact Dell Support for such a tool.

Comment: Dell support was contact and have said that the printer cannot be repaired without being disassembled. Since it is old, it is not guaranteed that parts can be bought. Basically, I will have to buy a new printer now.

Comment: I'm not sure that repairing the firmware requires a new part, but Dell will ask to be paid for any service, and in addition for the delivery costs. Investing money in an old printer is really not economical. A new printer might be cheaper...